# Is the word "patch" appropriate for source code update?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

I've just checked in Wikipedia for some context where I could use the word *patch*, but most of the example usages I found only refers to "Software update" but not "Source code update"

Is the word *patch* appropriate for source code update?

For example:

> Could we use that repository to submit our source code patches?

Comment: A "patch" is a "quick fix" to some software.  Precisely how it's represented (eg, in source or object code) is not implied by the term.

Comment: So not appropriate? Is there an alternative word for `update` that I could use in my example sentence?

Comment: It is appropriate, assuming the update you're taking about is a "quick fix" (which is itself a rather vague and nebulous term).  Ie, you would use the term mostly for bug fixes, not new function.

Comment: Ooh. Would you mind to re-post your comment as an answer instead so I could accept it? Thanks :)

Comment: How is it possible to update the software but not the source code?

Comment: @SomethingDark - Switches and lights.  I've done it many times.

Comment: @SomethingDark through injection? If you consider it as software update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A software "patch" is a "quick fix" -- generally a change of limited scope to fix bugs, vs a change to provide new function.

Precisely how the "patch" is presented (eg, in source code or object code) is not implied by the term.

(The term most likely was borrowed from hardware engineers, who would "patch" hardware to correct bugs by, eg, cutting wires in the backplane and soldering in new ones.  Originally programmers would perform the analogous surgery by using the switches and lights on the control panel to change memory locations containing hardware instructions.  But the term "stuck" to the concept of a "quick fix" even though the mechanism for applying the patch got further and further removed from the actual hardware.)